# want to find all the values returned by the url page

Tags: ajax, html, jquery, get

I want to use the list of  links for showing those on my page.
For that I am using ajax GET method,

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: "www.wcidevapps.com/salescentral/idisk/0001000383/iDisk/",
            success:function(response){
                $('li a').attr('href');
            }
        });
```

But, after the responded html how can I use those href links?
how can I use those links ?

Comment: you want to store it in variable..?

Comment: but I want to use all the href responded from that page

Comment: i have added answer have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this.

```
var listHref = new Array();

$.ajax(
{
    type:'GET',
    url: "www.wcidevapps.com/salescentral/idisk/0001000383/iDisk/",
    success:function(response)
    {
        $(response).find('li a').each(function()
        {
            listHref.push($(this).attr('href'));
        });

    }
});

console.log(listHref);
```

Comment: @Rahul_RJ that is just to see if all the href is inside of `listHref`...its for debug..

Comment: & one more in this the url "www.wcidevapps.com/salescentral/idisk/0001000383/iDisk/" is another url not in the current project thats why I got requested to page "http://sc.wcidevapps.com/www.wcidevapps.com/salescentral/idisk/0001000383/iDisk/" but instead of that I just want to request to url "http://www.wcidevapps.com/salescentral/idisk/0001000383/iDisk/"   
How can it be done?

Comment: @Rahul_RJ you need to add header to your ajax call as its against the javascript same origin policy...you need to send header that allow you to make request across domain...

Comment: I am doing cross domain ajax request but still it doesn't respond

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0,linkArr = [];

success:function(response){
    $(response).find('li a').each(function(){    
linkArr[i++]=$(this).attr('href');
}
});
```

Now you will have all the link href data in the Array called "linkArr"